# Drawing 3D line from x,y,z coordinates of start and end points of 2D line for trajectory modelling?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcscene

I have a polyline shapefile with over 13,000 lines which I want to display in 3D to crudely model the trajectories of particles being erupted from a volcano.

I have 2D lines which extend from the x,y coordinates of where each particle was ejected to where it lands. The Z coordinates for the start and end points of each line are also in the attribute table.

The end goal  is to have lines which are tilted down to the ground at the correct angle and location so I can find out how many of the particle trajectories intersect with buildings (which I've already extruded in 3D).

Answer (score 2):

Using the 3D Analyst extension, you can ingest the x, y, z coordinates from tables, each representing a feature in the input data set. A Python script like this can automate writing these tables, and then reading them all into the [ASCII 3D to Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/ascii-3d-to-feature-class.htm) tool:

```
import arcpy
import os

myworkspace = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Somewhere"        # your workspace
fc = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Somewhere\\myInput.shp"    # your input in your workspace
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)                       # we need its spatial reference
spatialRef = desc.spatialReference              #  for later.


# Going through each feature in the dataset, making an XYZ text file for each.
# We reference the OID, SHAPE, and Z-value fields in the feature class,
# assuming your z values are in "Zcoord".
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", "Zcoord"]):
    # Create a file for this feature/row that we'll append values to.
    with open(os.path.join(myworkspace, "feat" + str(row[0]) + ".XYZ"), "a") as thisFile:
        thisFile.write("x y z") # for the file header for each XYZ file
        # Step through each part of the feature (even if only one, as we assume in this case)
        for part in row[1]:
            # Step through each vertex in the feature part
            for pnt in part:
                # Write a line for each vertex as "x y z"
                thisFile.write("{} {}".format(pnt.X, pnt.Y) + " " + str(row[2])

# Now, our workspace directory has a bunch of .xyz files, each representing one feature
# in the original input feature class. Use ASCRII 3D to Feature Class to go 3D.
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
arcpy.ddd.ASCII3DToFeatureClass(myworkspace,
                                "XYZ", "out3D.shp", "POLYLINE",
                                z_factor = 1, input_coordinate_system = spatialRef,
                                "#", file_suffix = "XYZ")
```

Also, just be sure you're coordinates are in projected meters (or feet) for all three of x, y, and z, to ensure your angle calculations later are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem really easily using the "Feature To 3D By Attribute" tool.

Once you have your lines and you have the heights you want each end of the line to be elevated to in the attribute table, you can enter in the two heights using this tool.

[image: This is what the lines came out looking like in the end]